# Moove / Slide Several UIelement on the screen

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

With my actual code i can make one object moove

```
private void OnManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;         
}

private void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    ballTranslate.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
    ballTranslate.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
    savx = ballTranslate.X;
    savy = ballTranslate.Y;
}

private void OnManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

and my xaml :

```
<Image x:Name="ball"
    Source="/bal.png"
    ManipulationStarted="OnManipulationStarted" 
    ManipulationCompleted="OnManipulationCompleted" 
    ManipulationDelta="OnManipulationDelta" Canvas.Left="212" Canvas.Top="282">

    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ballTranslate"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

when I add an other Image(ball) and I try to moove one; the other one moove too.
And I'd like to add several balls with something like a button. (cause the goal of my game is to place object on the screen.
My question is how can I add an other ball with the same comportement ?

More XAML with an other image (but i'd like to not pass through XAML to add an image cause i dunno how many images i need;

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Canvas x:Name="CanMap" Margin="10,0,-10,0">
        <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="/textg.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="480" Width="752" Canvas.Left="-24" RenderTransformOrigin="0.499,0.512" CacheMode="BitmapCache" />
        <!-- <Image Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Source="/bal.png" MouseMove="MouseMoving" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Canvas.Left="337" Canvas.Top="239"/>-->
        <Image x:Name="ball"    
               Source="/bal.png"
               ManipulationStarted="OnManipulationStarted" 
               ManipulationCompleted="OnManipulationCompleted" 
               ManipulationDelta="OnManipulationDelta" Canvas.Left="447" Canvas.Top="323">

            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ballTranslate"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Image x:Name="ball2"
               Source="/bal.png"
               ManipulationStarted="OnManipulationStarted" 
               ManipulationCompleted="OnManipulationCompleted" 
               ManipulationDelta="OnManipulationDelta" Canvas.Left="120" Canvas.Top="310">

            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ballTranslate2"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

add image: (I can't use bitmap )

```
void AddImage(string src)
{
    Image image = new Image();

    Uri uri = new Uri(src, UriKind.Relative);
    ImageSource img = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(uri);
    image.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, img);
    RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
    image.ManipulationDelta += OnManipulationDelta;
    // Add additional handlers here..

    CanMap.Children.Add(image);
}
```

-->

```
private void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    var transform = (sender as UIElement).RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
    transform.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
    transform.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
    savex = transform.X;
    savey = transform.Y;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer:

```
void AddImage(string src)
{
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(src, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    bitmap.EndInit();

    var img = new Image()
    {
        Source = bitmap,
        RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform()
    }

    img.ManipulationDelta += OnManipulationDelta;
    // Add additional handlers here..

    CanMap.Children.Add(img);
}

void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    var transform = (sender as UIElement).RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
    transform.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
    transform.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
 }
```

Comment: thanks, i don"t add more Image to my XAML for the moment, i have added 1 but directly in my XAML. I want to do it in the back-end;

Comment: So you have two images in your XAML-file, right? Can you post the complete XAML? What exactly is it you want to do in Code-behind?

Comment: i want something like a bucket. Pick a 'ball' inside. Then I want to slide this ball like others. For the moment I can moove only one, if i try with others the first one moove too.

Comment: I need to see your XAML with more than one `Image` to help.

Comment: I have edit my first message. But i dont think its in XAMl. I want to do : "add(new image(ball))" in my code behind

Comment: OnManipulationDelta Method helped me a lot, but i'm getting syntaxic errors with the addimage one. Near "var img = new Image { ... }". And i think i can't used Bitmap for a windows phone project. But i already solved this problem. Thank you @nuke

Comment: Oh I forgot parentheses: `RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform() `. If you are not able to figure the rest out yourself just ask.

Comment: add an image is working, but when I click on it, the application crash. I added my new code.

Comment: "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XML-Simp.DLL but was not handled in user code

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued." At line : " var transform = (sender as UIElement).RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;" ( the Next line is in yellow so i suppose this is the error"

Comment: The Problem appears to be in this line of your newly posted code: `RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();` Try something like this instead: `image.SetValue(Image.RenderTransformProperty, new TranslateTransform());`

Comment: transform and image don't exist in the current context ><

Comment: transform is `null` in `OnManipulationDelta` because you don't assign your `RenderTransform` to image in `AddImage`. Have you tried the correction above?

Comment: correction above working :D. Thanks a lot about the time you gave to me. I was so stucked on this step>

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Good luck with your further projects!